# How necessary is it to use Redux in React and store data locally if you're using Firebase and its active listeners?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

Long story short, if I'm pulling data constantly from Firebase in my React App using active listeners, do I need to use Redux to store data locally as well?

I'm asking only about serious functionality reasons that would make the app break if Redux is not used in this scenario.

Comment: A short answer for a short story of a long story: no.

Comment: Need more details. What data are you using, what is your architecture, what is the status of a webapp. Actually redux is not required for react. They have a nice context api also

Comment: And its also easier to include redux, than remove from the app. My suggestion would be: Start without redux, and if you really need it, than include it.

Comment: In my view, this is solved. I just wanted an opinion on whether it would break. I can understand from all your answers that it should be working fine. (My project is indeed working fine). For context, I'm talking about a twitch.tv extension that I'm currently developing using Firestore as a backend. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Redux is not necessary

Redux is just one solution for holding state in your react application. You do **not** "need" it.

But What you do need is a way to cause a render with your data. Redux will do this with the hook or `mapStateToProps` function. Another way to do this would be to use the `useState` hook directly getting and setting the data at a component level. You could also use the `useContext` hook to put your firebase data inside your context. It all depends on the use case for your data, but there's plenty of resources out there for that.

What is nice about Redux is that you can make a connected listener that triggers a redux action each time the socket is triggered.

### Example Action Trigger I made of this some time ago

I would find a better way of stopping the same action triggering than I did here. Advantage to this code here is that your redux store is the same as your firebase structure and all under the key firebase.

```
/**
 * @description
 * this function adds a firebase socket listener. The listener will fire
 * an action every time the value is changed.
 *
 * @param {String} document - firebase document name (can be a path)
 * @param {String} key - uid for an item in the firebase
 * @returns {Function}
 */
const fetchReference = (document, key = null) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const documentReference = firebase.database().ref(document);
  const reference = key ? documentReference.child(key) : documentReference;

  reference.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const state = getState();
    const firebaseDocument = state.firebase[document];
    const snapshotValue = snapshot.val();

    if (
      firebaseDocument
      && firebaseDocument[key]
      && (JSON.stringify(firebaseDocument[key]) === JSON.stringify(snapshotValue))
    ) {
      return;
    }

    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_FIREBASE_REFERENCE,
      payload: snapshotValue,
      document,
      key,
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm aware of all these things, I just wanted an opinion on whether the app would break in any scenario if you don't have local state stored somewhere. Thank you @Joe Lloyd